Is the polytope of the dual of a bounded feasible linear program the dual of the polytope of that linear program?
If you have a bounded feasible linear program. Subject to $Ax \geq B$ and $x \geq 0$. The feasible region is a polyhedron. If you you have a set in $R^n$, you can apply a duality transform, sending a point $x \in R^n$ to a affine space $D(x) \to $ {$ a \ | \ \langle a, x \rangle = 1   $}. This sends polyhedra to polyhedra.
I'm trying to understand duality in the context of linear programming. Is there a relationship between these two forms of duality? Specifically, is the duality transform of the polyhedra of feasible points of the primal problem the same as the polyhedra of the dual?
I've tried to understand it just by looking at the explicit form a dual program, but I can't quite see if it makes sense or not.

I am assuming the duality transform you are referring to sends a polyhedron $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ to its polar dual, the set $P^* = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | \langle x,y \rangle \leq 1, \,\,\,\forall y \in P\}$. Under this assumption, if $P$ is the feasible region of a linear program $L$, it is not true that $P^*$ is the feasible region of the dual linear program $D$ of $L$.
To see this, consider the following linear program $L$:
\begin{align}
\max \,\,&x_1 + x_2 \,\, \text{subject to} \\
&x_1 \leq 1, \\
&x_2 \leq 1, \\
&x_1,x_2 \geq 0.
\end{align}
The feasible region of $L$ is $P = \{(x_1,x_2) | 0 \leq x_1 \leq 1, 0 \leq x_2 \leq 1\}$ (i.e. the square with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$). Now, one can check that the dual $D$ of $L$ is the same linear program and so the feasible region of $D$ is also $P$. But, the polar dual $P^*$ is not equal to $P$. This follows from the fact that $(1,1) \notin P^*$ since $\langle (1,1), (1,1)\rangle = 2 \not\leq 1$.
One connection between polar duals and linear programming is stated in Theorem 7 here. Roughly, it says that "linear optimization over $P$ is equivalent to the separation problem over $P^∗$" where $P^*$ is the polar dual of $P$.
